# Importing js library that doesn't have exports

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ngDraggable.js library in my node_modules folder which must be included as dependency as follows:

```
import draggable from 'ngDraggable';
```

ngDraggable.js doesn't have exports so I used the work around from some SO answer which I cannot find any more. It was suggested to use an index.js file withing the same folder, which would import ngDraggable.js and export it. For some reason this file was lost and I can't remember that 2 lines of code doing this:( I tried this, but it doesn't work at all:

```
import ngDraggable from './ngDraggable';
export default angular.module('ngDraggable', [ngDraggable]);
```

Error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"default":{"default":{"_invokeQueue":[],"_configBlocks":[],"_runBlocks":[],"requires":[{}],"name":"ngDraggable"}}} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/ng/areq?p0=module&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object
    at http://localhost:3000/index.js:17216:12

Where 'app' is the main module representing the application and "default" must the module that imports ngDraggable and exposes it for main module

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
import * as draggable from 'ngDraggable';
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is rather in the second line, which is responsible for export..

Answer (score 1):

I found the copy of missing file. Here's the code snippet

```
require('./ngDraggable.js');
module.exports = 'ngDraggable';
```